# Spring MockMvc is returning 200 instead of a 201. How to debug?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am attempting to test a controller with several HTTP verbs using Spring MockMvc. Currently `GET` and `DELETE` work as expected, but `PUT` and `PATCH` are not returning 201, when they should be.

The `PATCH` controller is setup as follows:

```
@CustomRequestMapping(method = PATCH, value = "/{api-root}")
public ResponseEntity patch(@PathVariable(value = "api-root") String id, @RequestBody ApiRoot apiRoot) {
     return apiRootService.softUpdate(id, apiRoot);
}
```

The `@CustomRequestMapping...` annotation just sets up `consumes` and `produces` to be a particular content type.

the `softUpdate()` method referenced above performs the following:

```
public ResponseEntity softUpdate(String id, ApiRoot apiRoot) {
    if (apiRoot.getId() == null) {
        apiRoot.setId(id);
    }

    ApiRootDocument updated = softUpdate(apiRoot);
    return ResponseEntity
            .created(EscapeUtil.buildUrl(applicationProperties.getHostname(), applicationProperties.getPort(), id))
            .body(updated);
}
```

This is working and tested outside of the MockMvc unit tests. It correctly returns a `201 Created` to Postman, with the body being the new JSON Object that was created as a result of the `PATCH`.

My test is setup as:

```
public void testPatchApiRootEndpoint() throws Exception {
    String testTitle = "New Test Title";

    // Mock the service call for softUpdate() to return 'created' in the same way that the method does
    when(apiRootService.softUpdate(TestData.apiRoot1.getId(), TestData.apiRoot1.withTitle(testTitle)))
            .thenReturn(ResponseEntity
                .created(URI.create(EscapeUtil.buildUrlString("localhost", "8001", TestData.apiRoot1.getId())))
                .body((ApiRootDocument) TestData.apiRoot1.withTitle(testTitle)));

    // Perform a patch update using a new title provided as key-value
    JsonObject titleJson = new JsonObject();
    titleJson.addProperty("title", testTitle);
    mockMvc.perform(patch("/{api-root}", TestData.apiRoot1.getId())
                .contentType(Constants.TAXII2_CONTENT_TYPE)
                .content(titleJson.toString()))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
}
```

Which results in a `200` being returned, instead of a `201`. I'm really confused, and it has been difficult to research. Most similar issues are finding 4XX response codes when they expect 2XX, and the solution is typically something to do with the setup of the request.

The only interesting logs I can seem to find are:

```
09:48:25.064 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Servlet '' configured successfully
09:48:25.208 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name '' processing PATCH request for [/api-root-1]
09:48:25.211 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /api-root-1
09:48:25.219 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity xor.bcmc.flarecloud.apiroot.controller.ApiRootController.patch(java.lang.String,xor.bcmc.taxii2.resources.ApiRoot)]
09:48:25.388 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Read [class xor.bcmc.taxii2.resources.ApiRoot] as "application/vnd.oasis.taxii+json;version=2.0" with [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@20921b9b]
09:48:25.428 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name '': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
09:48:25.428 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your mocked call not worked. You can easily check if you replace values to the any():

```
when(apiRootService.softUpdate(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())
.thenReturn(ResponseEntity
                .created(URI.create(EscapeUtil.buildUrlString("localhost", "8001", TestData.apiRoot1.getId())))
                .body((ApiRootDocument) TestData.apiRoot1.withTitle(testTitle)));
```

I just checked if you use wrong mock from controller is returned 200 status, but if mock is correct i got 201.

Comment: Thanks, this did indeed work, but I'm curious as to why Mockito and Spring can't detect the actual parameter values being passed in? Anyway, it works and covers the code I need it to, so I'll take it.

Comment: `Mockito.any()` in my example it is just for easily checking, of course in real life you should check actual values for example `Mockito.eq(TestData.apiRoot1.getId())` in your case